# How this_variable stores the keydown info?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am starting to learn how to code and I came across this snipped of code, and I want to know how this this_parameter is storing the information of the Keydown event?

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDraw);

function keyDraw(this_parameter){

    console.log(this_parameter);

}
```

Comment: What undefined variable?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it, I meant the parameter I called this_parameter, I want to understand how it works, how it is storing the keydown event information?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you called `this_parameter` is typically called `event` and is passed in to your function by the browser via an event listener (which you've defined). Your `keyDraw` function is an event handler, and is called by the browser whenever a `keydown` event is fired. The `keydown` event is fired when you press a keyboard key.

To learn more about the keydown event, visit the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event).